# Limpar Target em projetos JSF+JPA+Richfaces

Tags: java, jsf, jpa-2.0

Como posso limpar os Targets gerados do projeto quando realizamos o *deploy* para JBoss?

Comment: O que você chama de target? O que é isso?

Comment: target é uma pasta que ele gera no <name_project>-ejb, <name_project>-ear e no <name_project>-web

Comment: Por que você não apaga a pasta antes do deploy? É uma prática comum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver utilizando maven, é só rodar mvn clean